# How to make a Cassandra connection using CQL used to create a table?

Tags: tableau-api, cassandra-2.1

I am new to tableau, gone through the site before having this question posted, didn't found answer matching to my question.

I have connection established successfully to Cassandra using "DataStax cassandra ODBC driver 64bit windows", evrything is fine, filled all details like "keyspace name, table name as per documentation available in Datastax site".

But when I drag the available table to canvas it's keep on loading for minutes, what the database guy has told me about the data is it's more millions of data for one day, so we have 6months data and that to data gets updated for every 10 minutes, it;s for a reputed wind energy company.

My client has given me "" CQL used for creating table:

```
create table abc_data_test.machine_data
  (machine_id text, tag text, timestamp timestamp, value double, 
    PRIMARY KEY((machine_id, tag), timestamp)) 
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(timestamp DESC) 
    AND compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'LZ4Compressor' };"".
```

Where to keep this code?

I tried to insert in connection page it's giving a error. I am getting a new custom sql error (I placed the code in  "new custom sql" ) .

The time is still running, can be seen as:

> processing request: connecting to datasource, Elapsed time 87:09

The error from new custom sql is

> An error occured while commuicating with the datasource. [DataStax][CassandraODBC] (10) Error while executing a query in Cassandra:33562624: line 1.11 no viable alternative at input '1' (SELECT [TOP]1...)

I'm using windows 10 64bit, DataStax odbc driver 64bit-2.4.1 version,DSE is4.8 and later .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass DDL sql into the custom sql box. If the Cassandra connection supports the [Initial SQL](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_initialsql.html) option, you could pass it there. Then your custom sql would be some sort of select statement. Otherwise, create the table in Cassandra then connect to that table from Tableau.